# Using Child Class In Android

Tags: android, inheritance

Sorry, I'm a newbie to Java and Android...

I've made an app that has a big main activity, I'm wanting to split it up into some child classes to make things easier to read, edit etc.

From my main class I (think) I am instantiating, and calling the child class, from within OnResume :

```
  SetupButtons SetupButtonsObject = new SetupButtons ();
          SetupButtonsObject.buildthem();
```

And in the child class I do:

```
        class SetupButtons extends main {

     void buildthem(){
//a load of things to setup buttons
}

}
```

The code I am using in buildthem() works fine when used in the main class, but is giving a nullpointer exception when used in the child class.

do I need to pass the main context to the child or something?

Many Thanks 
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Activity` class isn't supposed to be instantiated by developer directly, leave this work to the android. If you wish to split it up why do you extend your main activity? You rather need to divide your app in logical parts as Nanne said.

Comment: I dont think I am instantiating Activity am I? I am trying to divide it up into logical parts...I thought using child classes would be a good way. Surely if I wanted to use the variables from the main activity I need to extend it?

Comment: I'm not sure because I can't see your code, but `class SetupButtons extends main` and you told about your main activity, so i decided that the `main` here is your main activity. If you want to use the variables from the main activity you can pass them as parameteres to your "logical part" classes' constructors.

Answer (score 1):

Anything you use in the childclass that is not set there, but set in the main class, you must in some way get from the main class. So yeah, you need some context.

But before you do that: you might want to divide your app in classes that are logical parts of your sollution, as you can read in any OOP description. So not just chop it up in parts because it makes it smaller, chop it up in logical units that are actual good objects.

A quick type, hope I did not make any mistakes here, but see comments in child class.

```
class Parent{
   public static int foo = 1;
   public static int bar = 0;

   public function somefunction(){
      bar = 1;
      myChild = new Child();
   }

}

class Child extends Parent{
   //you can find foo = 1
   //but not bar = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, All the variables I use in the child are set in the main class as defined as static public.So I thought through inheritance, they should be accessable by child?

Comment: Thanks. I did some more tests by simplifying the code in my child class. It seems the variables are being accessed fine, and can be updated from the child class. It's the button's findviewbyID, which is used in the child that seems to be the problem.

Comment: Most of the time that means that you have not used 'setContentView' yet, or the ID you are looking for is not in that content view. But that might be another question :).

Comment: I'm using  setContentView(R.layout.main); in the main class. Not sure if the child class can determine to use this contentview though? Maybe I should start another question..thanks for your input anyway

Comment: a new question might be best: it could be something like you needing to use `context.findviewbyid`?

Answer (score 0):

In same class you can call that method directly. Like `buildthem();`